# How to get P4 CL details without installing P4 on PC?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am looking for a way to get to know the CL details (files submitted/changed) without sctually installing the P4. I have checked the P4 official site and this site also for answers.

If P4 is installed, we get the module p4 and all the answers and expecting this.The answer is

`p4 files @=<CL>`

Is there a way to do this without installing the P4. I have the Server details , Depot and authentication.

Thanks in Advance
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

If the server has P4Web or Swarm set up, you can browse it that way.  For an example of what this looks like, see the Perforce Workshop, aka the Perforce Public Depot:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/

Contact the administrator of the Perforce server in question to see if they have a Swarm instance, and if not, ask them to set one up.